# AWS MSK Default enable.auto.commit setting

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

Does AWS' Managed Streaming for Apach Kafka (MSK) have `enable.auto.commit` set to `true` by default? I't not showing up in the docs, and I want to make sure that my consumers are properly committing offsets.

Or does MSK follow the Kafka process cited [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration) where if a consumer sets a ConsumerGroup ID, then MSK automatically sets `enable.auto.commit = true` by default?

Comment: MSK is a hosted server. It doesn't modify client settings

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ah, this is a consumer setting. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group.id` and `enable.auto.commit` would be set in the same location, in the consumer client, and are not controlled by the server-side, so there is no such "default" in MSK or any other Kafka environment that is controlled outside your code.

Answer (score 0):

`enable.auto.commit` is a consumer setting, not a cluster setting. The consumer is responsible for directing Kafka to commit its offest to the `__consumer_offsets` topic.